# Menu visibility toggle method

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I've just created a method that toggles menu visibility. At the moment I've gone with an `if`..`else` which checks my flag and acts appropriately. Can anyone offer any suggestions on how to make this snippet better? Maybe it shouldn't all live in the same snippet? Maybe I should be combining the show/hide logic that's duplicated in the `if`..`else`?

```
onNavTriggerClick: function(event) {

            var $currentTarget = $(event.currentTarget);

            if(this._navOpen) {
                Backbone.Events.trigger('hide:menu');
                $currentTarget.removeClass('is-active');
                this._navOpen = false;
            } else {
                Backbone.Events.trigger('show:menu');
                $currentTarget.addClass('is-active');
                this._navOpen = true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already mentioned the duplication, so let's address that issue.

First, I'd move the assignment to a common block so it's clear that
you're toggling the visibility.

Then for toggling the CSS class I found the
[`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function, so maybe
go with that.

After that moving the assignment to the top, then working based on the
new state gives me this:

```
onNavTriggerClick: function(event) {
  this._navOpen = !this._navOpen;
  Backbone.Events.trigger(this._navOpen ? 'show:menu' : 'hide:menu');
  $(event.currentTarget).toggleClass('is-active', this._navOpen);
}
```

Looks a bit more concise.